# Run a function every N calls to an API in a distributed environment

Tags: python, django

I need to run a function `send_user_survey` to every 100 users who hit a certain endpoint. I can't simple increment a counter locally because I have multiple machines, so 50 hits on one machine and 50 on another should trigger one run of `send_user_survey`.

I could store the count on the database but using a SQL database to lock and increment on every API call doesn't seem like the right solution, especially since this API gets hit pretty hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I went with is to use dynamoDB expressions for atomic operations that return the newly incremented value, implemented in the [distributed_counter](https://github.com/wontonst/distributed-counter-py) package.

The end solution looks something like

```
counter = DistributedCounter('mytable')
if not counter.increment('mykey', 1) % 100:
    send_user_survey()
    counter.decrement('mykey', 100)
```